# Route with Waypoints Free/Paid

Tags: skmaps

With the updates of Skobbler on 2.4, I saw that there is a new method for passing waypoints en route.

Is this method free?

```
- (void)calculateRouteWithSettings:(SKRouteSettings *)route customLocations:(NSArray*)locations;
```

Because the Custom Routing is paid, but with the GPX file.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is an alternative to GPX tracks (removing the need to create an actual GPX file) - it is also regarded as custom routing as the technique behind is the same (create a route from an arbitrary sent of points) and it requires a commercial license to be used in commercial apps.